Halmos and the Axiom of Choice: attitudes in 1960
In introducing the Axiom of Choice, Halmos (Naive Set Theory) states a position that (approximately) "worrying about the use of the Axiom is no longer a thing." His overall tone is extremely matter-of-fact, reflecting none of the, um, angst that has surrounded the Axiom as documented in Moore.
Is this reflecting the mathematical zeitgeist in 1960, or just Halmos' view? It is my impression that this isn't an overwhelming consensus of modern mathematicians - plenty of things are very careful to state their dependence on Choice and/or to avoid it.
(I could really point to a paragraph that says: 'Mathematicians used to strive to eliminate the use of the Axiom ... but don't any longer.')

I suspect the concern is less about the philosophical underpinnings and more about what framework was used to prove a particular result.

Almost thirty years ago I had homological algebra classes by a renowned German number theorist. When it came to the proof of the existence of injective resolutions he announced that this class will be held by his assistent who has a `more modern attitude'. The issue was the axiom of choice. The older I get the more sympathetic I am towards this elegant solution.

My absolute ignorance, but I assume that "documented in Moore" means in "Zermelo's Axiom of Choice: Its Origins, Development, and Influence (Dover Books on Mathematics)
by Gregory H. Moore." Correct? (I did a search on Moore and choice, obviously...)

@peterag Yes, that's the Moore.

@HCH apologies that this is off-topic from the AC, but in response to your comment above: my esteemed supervisor, while teaching CFT,  recounted having taken a course taught by Brauer: at one point Brauer railed that the youngsters ("the kids these days") don't even think to check that the construction of the Brauer group rests on sets (and not classes).  [I heard this story quite a while ago, but less than thirty years ago, so I hope I am remembering it correctly.]

@peter a g: As a mathematical physicist I see set theory as a preliminary solution (and am pretty ignorant). Everything of value has to be sort of constructive in the end.  I worked with particle physicists and found that they ignore set theory completely and do not take it seriously: `I believe in procedures" they say. They are quite knowledgeble about other areas of mathematics. There is more than one truth according to Leibniz's preestablished harmony.

One important difference between the late and early 20th century in this respect is the knowledge, in the latter, of the following two technical facts:

Godel's introduction and analysis of the constructible universe $L$ showed that if $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent then so is $\mathsf{ZFC}$; and moreover, "$T$ and $T+\mathsf{AC}$ are equiconsistent" is true (via the same-ish proof) for a wide variety of choices of $T$. So from a purely internal-consistency standpoint, choice is rarely the issue.

In fact, Godel's argument shows more than this: since $L$ and $V$ agree on all arithmetical facts, any proof of an arithmetical fact which uses the axiom of choice can be de-choicified. So, for example, the proof of Fermat's last theorem can't possibly rely on choice in a crucial way. This phenomenon, called absoluteness, was pushed further by first Mostowski and then Shoenfield, the latter proving (building on the former) that any $\Pi^1_2$ sentence provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone. Moreover, this proof translation process is completely explicit: it's a subtle argument, but there's no "logical shenanigans" (as I once heard suggested) at play.  (At this point I should also mention Platek's Eliminating the continuum hypothesis although it's not directly relevant.)


So the safety of AC was established by the 60s (Godel's work is from 1938, and Shoenfield's is from 1961) in a way that simply wasn't in sight during the period Moore was writing about.

Basic mathematical facts rely on fragments of AC, where a good recent overview can be found in Herrlich's monograph "Axiom of Choice".
A nice example is that ZF cannot prove the local equivalence between sequential and normal continuity.
Many other examples exist and perhaps mathematicians therefore "have given up" on noting every little use of AC, except for the relatively "strong" cases.

Halmos's attitude is untenable, as many (though not all) mathematicians always preferred and still prefer to avoid the axiom of choice in their arguments (though they perhaps accept its use in the definition of some fundamental concepts).  Furthermore, Halmos fails to make a crucial distinction.  A majority of mathematicians are comfortable with using the Axiom of Countable Choice (ACC) and the slightly stronger Axiom of Dependent Choice (ADC).  These axioms have none of the paradoxical consequences such as the Banach-Tarski Theorem.  Neither does ZF+ADC prove the existence of nonprincipal ultrafilters.  In this sense, ZF+ADC constitutes a "safer" epistemological foundation.
Ironically, while Halmos does mention the axiom of choice in his textbook Measure Theory, he overlooks an implicit reliance on ACC in his argument on page 42 proving the $\sigma$-additivity of the Lebesgue measure.
An anecdotal search reveals additional influential mathematicians with
qualms about the axiom of choice:
*Alain Connes;
*Pierre Deligne, who writes that he detests (répugne) the axiom of
choice on page 139(315) of

Deligne, Pierre.  La conjecture de Weil. II.  Inst. Hautes Études
Sci. Publ. Math. No. 52 (1980), 137–252.

*Theo Buhler and Dietmar Salamon, who don't "detest" it but are
sensitive to its use in functional analysis; see

Bühler, Theo; Salamon, Dietmar A. Functional analysis. Graduate
Studies in Mathematics, 191. American Mathematical Society,
Providence, RI, 2018

where they point out explicitly which results depend on AC.
*Roger Penrose, who wrote:

"Most mathematicians would probably regard the axiom of choice as 'obviously true', while others might regard it as a somewhat questionable assertion which might even be false (and I am myself inclined, to some extent, towards this second viewpoint)."

Thus, a number of influential mathematicians prefer effective (a better term than
"constructive") arguments when they are presented with both
possibilities.  Of course, if there is actually a simpler argument
using choice/ultrafilters and the like, many will favor the simpler
argument for reasons of elegance.
The idea that results such as Shoenfield Absoluteness would have been sufficiently familiar to working mathematicians so as to influence them toward acceptance of AC (as implied in this answer) is in my view more dubious than the idea that many mathematicians prefer more effective arguments to less effective ones.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
